В Linux настроить папку, чтобы при копировании в нее файлы получали владельца и группу от папки, исполняемость сохраняли свою
милые дамы и уважаемые господа!
Дано:
Есть хост с Linux. Есть папка у которой владелец=dirown, группа=users. Права на папку такие: drwxrwxr--.
Требуется:
Что-то сделать с папкой чтобы при копировании в нее файлов, не важно откуда, внутри хоста или с другой системы копируемые файлы получали владельца и группу точно такие же, как есть у папки. А вот признак исполняемый или нет - должен оставаться таким, какой у файла-оригинала.
Прошу обратить внимание, что вариант: "сначала скопировать, потом поменять атрибуты, используя chown и chmod" - не подходит.
И еще: я спрашиваю КАК сделать, а не ЧТО делать. Прошу, не забывайте об этом.
Зарание благодарен!
Навеки ваш!

imho это невозможно.

Поменять группу - можно, владельца - нельзя

"что делать" -  пиши свою фс :D вопрос Аля "хочу взломать Пентагон, я спрашиваю КАК это сделать, а не что"

Пишите наблюдателя за папкой (inotify), который бы при появлении новых файлов в папке правил бы им аттрибуты.

Половина задачи прояснилась.
Пользователя, действительно, менять не получается, а с группой - лучше.
Выполнил: chmod g+s dirname.
Получил права на папку: drwxrwsr--
Теперь файлы при создании/копировании в dirname получают группу users.
Осталось разобраться, как сделать чтобы права на эти фалы были, как у оригиналов.

@StainlessCat, если копировать файлы командой cp -a ..., то права должны сохраняться. (вообще, вы не описали в вопросе  всю процедуру, т.е. каким именно образом файлы могут попадать в ваш каталог)
